# Python formulae calculation from user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, formula

Im am very new to Python 2.7 and I dont know what structure would be best to use for this script.

I think my problem is that I dont know how to make Python store the user inputs for future use in the script..

Whole script.

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from sys import argv

prompt = '>'

# user inputs.. values to be used in calculation
ri = int(input("inre bockningsradie i mm:"))
L1 = int(input("längd på plåt som 'står':"))
L2 = int(input("längd på plåt som 'ligger':"))
t = int(input("tjocklek på plåt:"))
a1 = int(input("bockningsvinkel i grader:"))

# 
L1_total = L2 - t - ri
L2_total = (L2, - t, - ri,)
Lb_total = multiply(ri, pi) / 180
rn = multiply(t, k) + rn
k = divide(r, t)
L_total = ( L1, + L2, + Lb_total)

print "beräkning av ämneslängd för kantbokning"
print "ämneslängden är: ", L_total
```

Runetime error:
    Runtime error:

```
z@z ~/Documents/scripts_r_w $ python amneslangd.py

inre bockningsradie i mm:213
längd på plåt som 'står':123
längd på plåt som 'ligger':123 
tjocklek på plåt:123
bockningsvinkel i grader:123

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "amneslangd.py", line 18, in <module>
L1_total = L2 - t - ri
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Formulae source:

Can be found at: http://s30.postimg.org/gq2vqzz1b/formula.jpg

---------------------------------MISSION COMPLETE-----------------------------------------

Thanks for your input guys! After fixing the first problem, more errors spawned! Aside from runtime errors I found some schematic errors in there aswell.. But below is the version that works as intended.. A little cleaned-up...

Side question: Is there a way to make float(input) also accept commas and periods as in 0,72 instead/or 0.72?

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from sys import argv

print "\n"
print "\tScript som räknar ut ämneslängden för kantbockning i plåt!"
print "\n\tOBS. Korrektionsfaktorn i tabell kanske står som: 0,72"
print "\tDu ska skriva in värdet som 0.72"
# line below means exchange comma(,) for a period(.)..
print "\tAlltså, byt ut comma(,) mot en punkt(.)!" 
print "\n"

# user inputs.. values to be used in calculation
ri = int(input("(ri) inre bockningsradie i mm: "))
L1 = int(input("(L1) vertikal kanthöjd: "))
L2 = int(input("(L2) horizontel kanthöjd: "))
t = int(input("(t) tjocklek på plåt: "))
a1 = int(input("(a) bockningsvinkel: "))
k = ri / t

# prints k as integer so user can look up k1 from a table
print "\nVad är (k)korrekktionsfaktor i kolumn: %d, rad: %d?" % (k, a1)
# below prompts the user for the value he got when looking up "k" from table
k1 = float(input("\nk = "))


l1_total = L1 - t - ri  # returns l1
l2_total = L2 - t - ri  # returns l2
rn = (t * k1) / 2 + ri 
lb_total = (rn * 3.14 * a1) / 180 # returns lb
L_total = (l1_total + l2_total  + lb_total) # returns L

print "\n\t(L)Ämneslängden är: ", L_total
print "\n"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's actually the code that's being executed?  It works for me when I try it.  (Or at least it gets past that line -- `multiply` isn't defined, so I get a `NameError`.) Add `print "here!"` after `prompt` to check.

Comment: I suppose `L2_total = (L2, - t, - ri,)` is a typo and you don't actually have commas there?

Comment: @DSM try adding `from numpy import *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that cannot do a mathematical operation between an integer and a string:

```
L1_total = L2 - t - ri
```

You must check the input values ​​and convert them to the same type if necessary, and then do operations on them.